# jsTree integration Mysql schema

Tags: mysql, jstree

Greetings,

I have some big datasets that would look great in a hierarchy format offered by jsTree.
After several attempts my understanding of the schema is just shy of understanding.
'left','right','position','title`,'level'

http://www.jstree.com/demo

Now can anyone shed some insight to the `left`, and `right` entries?
I cannot find any documentation on jsTree but really need to complete the project soon.
The relationship for 'right' doubles total entries? Not sure but feel jsTree is quite an intuitive design and would like to use it.

Much Obliged,

-Peter

Answer (score 1):

It's called the "nested set" model. You can read more about it in this tutorial from MySQL:

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/